# Failed to send an email with php mail() function

Tags: php, html

I am trying to send an HTML email to user after submitting a form but failed to send an email with PHP `mail()` function. I am working on the same thing from last 2 hours & I couldn't find the solution.

Below is my code, please give your suggestions.

```
<?php
$replyemail="sales@companyname.com";

if (!isset($_POST['email']))
{
 echo "<script language=\"JavaScript\"><!--\n ";
 echo "top.location.href = \"$valid_ref1\"; \n// --></script>";
 exit;
}

function is_forbidden($str,$check_all_patterns = true)
{
 $patterns[0] = 'Content-Type:';
 $patterns[1] = 'mime-version';
 $patterns[2] = 'multipart/mixed';
 $patterns[3] = 'Content-Transfer-Encoding';
 $patterns[4] = 'to:';
 $patterns[5] = 'cc:';
 $patterns[6] = 'bcc:';
 $forbidden = 0;
 for ($i=0; $i<count($patterns); $i++)
  {
   $forbidden = eregi($patterns[$i], strtolower($str));
   if ($forbidden) break;
  }
 //check for line breaks if checking all patterns
 if ($check_all_patterns AND !$forbidden) $forbidden = preg_match("/(%0a|%0d|\\n+|\\r+)/i", $str);
 if ($forbidden)
 {
  echo "<font color=red><center><h3>STOP! Message not sent.</font></h3><br><b>
        The text you entered is forbidden, it includes one or more of the following:
        <br><textarea rows=9 cols=25>";
  foreach ($patterns as $key => $value) echo $value."\n";
  echo "Error";
  exit();
 }
 else return $str;
}

$email = is_forbidden($_POST["email"]);
$contact = is_forbidden($_POST["contact"]);
$comments = is_forbidden($_POST["comments"]);

$ccemail = "From: $email" . "\r\n" .
"CC: demo@companyname.com";

$mailHeader = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$mailHeader .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$mailHeader .= "From: " . $email . "\r\n";
$mailHeader .= "Cc: demo@companyname.com\r\n";

$themessage = 'Hello';

mail("$replyemail","Thanks for Register","$themessage","$mailHeader");
?>
```

Comment: do you get any errors? Have you enabled error_reporting in php and/or your php-server? Furthermore: Do you run the code on a localhost or "a real server"?

Comment: I am not getting any errors..

Comment: have you tried to add ``error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', '1');`` to the beginning of your code? Is your code running on a localhost or a webserver?

Comment: Have you checked spam folder ?

Comment: have you made sure to enable the mail-sending (eg. mercury, sendmail) on your server ?

Comment: my code is running on webserver / i have also checked spam folder

Comment: I would suggest to copy a sample send-mail from somewhere and check if the mail-function itself is actually working. This could exclude the possibility of errors in your code. If its still not working: Do you have access to the logfiles or the server itself? You might wanna check if the mail service is running and not throwing any errors

Answer (score 0):

I also got stuck once. I would recommend you to try different email addresses (I figured out that mails were being sent to gmail only) and if it doesn't works then contact your hosting service (free hosting are unreliable as far as using PHP mail() function is concerned).